# Python function that organizes values in a lis, dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

The scale rates the hardness of an object
A function should return a dictionary organizing the objects from such a list into four categories.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Please show your attempts; SO is not a code-writing or homework-doing service.

Comment: @ScottAllen: You should show your attempt towards getting the solution. 

Anyway, I have a solution which might help you learn stuffs in Python, check the answer. Sadly, someone downvoted it without giving a valid reason to do so.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a `dict` with keys and empty lists.
- With each iteration append the value to corresponding key.

/

```
def func(ls):
    dict_ = {'soft':[], 'medium':[],'hard':[], 'very hard':[]}
    for i in ls:
        # print(i)
        if i[1] >= 1 and i[1] <=3:
            dict_['soft'].append(i[0])
        elif i[1] >= 3.1 and i[1] <= 5:
            dict_['medium'].append(i[0])
        elif i[1] >= 5.1 and i[1] <=8:
            dict_['hard'].append(i[0])
        elif i[1] >= 8.1 and i[1] <=10:
            dict_['very hard'].append(i[0])

    return dict_

print(func(rocks))
```

**output**

```
{'hard': ['silicon', 'emerald'],
 'medium': ['nickel'],
 'soft': ['talc', 'lead', 'copper'],
 'very hard': ['boron', 'diamond']}
```

Answer (score -1):

### One more way of solving it is using `dict comprehension` and `setdefault` method of dict:

```
rocks = [('talc', 1), ('lead', 1.5), ('copper', 3), \
         ('nickel', 4), ('silicon', 6.5), ('emerald', 7.5),\
         ('boron', 9.5), ('diamond', 10)]

aa = {}
bb = {aa.setdefault("soft",[]).append(k) if 1 <= v <= 3 \
      else aa.setdefault("medium",[]).append(k) if 3.1 <= v <= 5 \
      else aa.setdefault("hard",[]).append(k) if 5.1 <= v <= 8 \
      else aa.setdefault("very hard",[]).append(k) \
      for k, v in rocks}
print (aa)

# Result--> {'soft': ['talc', 'lead', 'copper'], 'medium': ['nickel'], 'hard': ['silicon', 'emerald'], 'very hard': ['boron', 'diamond']}
```

I hope this even helps you to understand the usage of setdefault. :)